# I am writing Java Program to validate the correct closure of bracket/parenthesis but it's not working. Can someone help me by indicating the problem?

Tags: stack

Input Format

There will be multiple lines in the input file, each having a single non-empty string. You should read input till end-of-file.

The part of the code that handles input operation is already provided in the editor.

Output Format

For each case, print 'true' if the string is balanced, 'false' otherwise.

Input - (({()})))
Expected Output - false
Actual Output - true

```
public static boolean paranValidate(String input) {
    String[] chrArray = input.split("");
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chrArray.length; i++) {
        if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("{"))
            stack.push("}");
        if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("("))
            stack.push(")");
        if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("["))
            stack.push("]");
        if (!stack.empty()) {
            if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("}") && chrArray[i].trim().equals(stack.peek()))
                stack.pop();
            if (chrArray[i].trim().equals(")") && chrArray[i].trim().equals(stack.peek()))
                stack.pop();
            if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("]") && chrArray[i].trim().equals(stack.peek()))
                stack.pop();
            
        }
    }

    return stack.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Solution is:

```
class stackExample {

public static boolean paranValidate(String input) {
    String[] chrArray = input.split("");
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chrArray.length; i++) {
        if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("{"))
            stack.push("}");
        if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("("))
            stack.push(")");
        if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("["))
            stack.push("]");
        if (!stack.empty()) {
            if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("}") && chrArray[i].trim().equals(stack.peek()))
                stack.pop();
            if (chrArray[i].trim().equals(")") && chrArray[i].trim().equals(stack.peek()))
                stack.pop();
            if (chrArray[i].trim().equals("]") && chrArray[i].trim().equals(stack.peek()))
                stack.pop();
        }
        else return false;
    }

    return stack.empty();
}
```